# any way to manipulate airplane mode programatically? android

Tags: java, android, mode, airplane-mode

I want to turn on or off airplane mode for a battery saving app im making.
Is there really no way to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
package com.example.airplaneog;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        final Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        if (getAPstate() == true){
            testButton.setText("Turn Airplane Mode OFF");           
        }else {

            testButton.setText("Turn Airplane Mode ON");
        }
    }

    public boolean getAPstate(){
        return Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void apmodeonoff(View view){

        final Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        boolean st;

        if (getAPstate() == true){
            testButton.setText("Turn Airplane Mode OFF");
            Settings.System.putBoolean(getContentResolver(),  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
            st = false;


        }else {
            testButton.setText("Turn Airplane Mode ON");
            Settings.System.putBoolean(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
            st = true;
        }

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
         intent.putExtra("state",  st);
         sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

When i run the application on my android nexus 7, nothing happens... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not something that I would want an application to be monkeying with on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Settings.System.putInt` instead of `Settings.System.putBoolean`.

```
if (getAPstate() == true){
            testButton.setText("Turn Airplane Mode OFF");
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
            st = false;


        }else {
            testButton.setText("Turn Airplane Mode ON");
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
            st = true;
        }
```

Comment: This will not work as of API Level 17.

Comment: This won't work from Android 4.2 onwards. Best to check for API level first then take the user to the settings screen for them to manually toggle the mode.

Comment: so theres no way to do it? I want to make a battery saving application that turns airplane mode on and off in periodic times